# Select 11 items in decreasing or increasing order from a set of 101

Tags: combinatorics

101 people stand in a line, all of them different heights.  Show it is possible to find 11 people so that the order of their heights in line (not necessarily next to each other) is increasing or decreasing.

I initially wanted to partition with sticks and crosses, but this left me with an enormous amount of combinations.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a job for the Pigeonhole Principle!

Answer (score 1):

This is a specific case of the [Erdős-Szekeres theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem). This can be proved using the pigeonhole principle; you’ll find such a proof in the linked article.